# Link to custom action in polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have project model that has many tasks. Both project and tasks can have many discussions, and therefore I made Discussions polymorphic model(see below).

I wish to be able to click the link and mark 'discussion' as finished.

The way I went on to do it is to make a custom action in the 'discussion controller' that changes the boolean value of the 'finished' attribute from false to true. How to make that link_to helper in the discussion show page succesfully route to that custom action in the discussions controller? Also, is this the best practice to do this?

**Discussion model**

```
  1 class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base  
  4   belongs_to :user
  5   belongs_to :discussionable, :polymorphic => true 
 28 end
```

**Project model**

```
  1 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base 
  7   has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  8   has_many :discussions, :as => :discussionable, :dependent => :destroy
 24 end
```

**Task model**

```
  1 class Task < ActiveRecord::Base          
  7   belongs_to :project      
 14   has_many :discussions, :as => :discussionable, :dependent => :destroy
 27 end
```

So far my link_to helper looks like below, but it doesnt work(doesnt strike the custom 'finish' action as I want)...

**Discussion show**

```
7   <%= link_to 'Finish discussion', polymorphic_path([@parent, @discussion]), :action => 'finish' %>
```

This is this **custom finish action in discussion controller**.(I have before_filter that defines this @discussion variable from params[:id])

```
 33   def finish
 34     if @discussion.update_attribute(:finished, true)
 35       flash[:notice] = "it worked"    
 36       else
 37       flash[:alert] = 'You must be an admin to do that'
 38     end
 39   end
```

I also haven't fiddled with routes.rb, as I don't know if I have to.

**Routes.rb**

```
  1 PrjctMngr::Application.routes.draw do                 
 13     
 14   # PROJECTS
 15   resources :projects do
 16     resources :tasks
 17     resources :discussions
 18   end
 19 
 20   # TASKS
 21   resources :tasks do
 22     resources :subtasks
 23     resources :discussions
 24   end
 31 
 32   # DISCUSSIONS
 33   resources :discussions do
 34     resources :comments    
 35   end
 36 
 37 end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <%= link_to 'Finish discussion', polymorphic_path([@parent, @discussion], :action => 'finish'), :method => :put %>
```

action option is for the path helper, not tag helper ;)

```
all assuming you have route set up propery
#routes.rb
resources :tasks do 
  resources :discussions do
    put :finish, :on => :member
  end
end
```

Comment: than I get this error > ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `finish_task_discussion_path' for #<#<Class:0xaad7c6c>:0xb3865868> ..... Why is that? Also, I haven't touched my routes.rb file to take care of this custom action. Should have I?

Comment: indeed you should have, updatad response

Comment: I have added the routes to the question, can you please use that to show me how I should hhave edited it?

Comment: shouldn't that be a put request?

Comment: yes better if you update the model. don't forget to save it in the action.

Comment: how should the link_to look like if I use put request?

Comment: now I get this error >> ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template discussions/finish, application/finish with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. what in the world?

Comment: I figured that the error is because of the finish action. I updated the question for you to see how I wrote it. what is wrong?

Comment: feels like an online tutoring session :) see my edited response, if your view templates and controller code are ok, it should work.

Comment: thank you so much. it now really does change the attribute from false to true. however my spec is failing and I don't know why. I'll accept your answer here, and if you want to be extra awesome, come check here why my spec is failing... thx again :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800378/test-failing-even-though-the-thing-it-is-testing-is-passing